# Set properties of an object to be relative to another property of the same object

Tags: c#

I have this method that detects a collision between the ball and the left paddle in the classic game "Pong". I have made variables for the different parts of the ball and the paddle, in order to make my collision detection method easier to understand. Here is the method (and it does work).

```
public bool DetectBallPaddle1Collision() {

            var ballBottom = _ball.Y + Ball.Width;
            var ballTop = _ball.Y;
            var ballLeft = _ball.X;
            var ballRight = _ball.X + Ball.Width;
            var paddle1Bottom = _paddle1.Y + Paddle.Height;
            var paddle1Top = _paddle1.Y;
            var paddle1Left = PlayerPaddle.X;
            var paddle1Right = PlayerPaddle.X + Paddle.Width;

            if (ballTop < paddle1Bottom &&
                ballBottom > paddle1Top &&
                ballLeft < paddle1Right) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I would now like to refactor this, to have the variables for the different parts of the ball, in the ball class, like so:

```
namespace Pong.Core.Models
{
    public abstract class Ball : IBall
    {
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int VX { get; set; }
        public int VY { get; set; }
        public static int Width;
        public static int Speed;
        public int Bottom { get; set; }
        public int Top { get; set; }
        public int Left { get; set; }
        public int Right { get; set; }

        public Ball() {
            this.setDirection ("left");
            Bottom = Y + Ball.Width;
            Top = Y;
            Left = X;
            Right = X + Ball.Width;
        }
```

Which enables me to change the ball/paddle1 collision detection method to this:

```
public bool DetectBallPaddle1Collision() {

            var paddle1Bottom = _paddle1.Y + Paddle.Height;
            var paddle1Top = _paddle1.Y;
            var paddle1Left = PlayerPaddle.X;
            var paddle1Right = PlayerPaddle.X + Paddle.Width;

            if (_ball.Top < paddle1Bottom &&
                _ball.Bottom > paddle1Top &&
                _ball.Left < paddle1Right) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Theoretically this should work, but it doesn't, the ball now goes through the paddle. This should work because a property is a method, and is supposed to keep updating if it is relative to another property, correct? This is why I made the ball.Bottom, .Top, .Left and .Right, properties with getters and setters rather than fields which would not keep updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify properties with { get; set; } what happens is the compiler is creating a private field and keeps the property value in it.

Setting the Top property value to Y in the constructor will put that initial value of Y into that private field and that value will never get updated as Y changes.

Instead, implement your properties like this:

(This will work assuming that X and Y are being updated during the game)

```
public class Ball : IBall
{
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int VX { get; set; }
    public int VY { get; set; }
    public static int Width;
    public static int Speed;

    public int Top
    {
        get
        {
            return Y; 
        }
    }

    public int Left
    {
        get
        {
            return X;
        }
    }

    public int Right
    {
        get
        {
            return X + Ball.Width;
        }
    }

    public int Bottom
    {
        get
        {
            return Y + Ball.Width;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have independent properties and dependent properties.

Independent properties are the ones that their values are not calculated and they present [degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom) in the system.

Dependent properties on the other hand, are properties of which value is calculated from other independent (and dependent) properties.

I will assume that `X`, `Y`, and `Width` and independent properties. And that `Bottom`, `Top`, `Left`, and `Right` are dependent properties.

Here is an example of how you would define `Top`:

I will assume that `X` and `Y` present the center of the ball.

```
public int Top
{
    get
    {
        return Y - (Height / 2);
    }
    set
    {
        Y = value + (Height / 2);
    }
}
```

So, when the consumer is asking for the value of the `Top` property, we calculate it from `Y` and `Height`. And when the consumer sets the value of this property, we change the `Y` property accordingly.

Please note that I am assuming that the point (0,0) is on the top-left corner of the screen. The equations would need to change if this is not the case.